# Enlarge image of marker on google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

How can I enlarge icon of marker? I have an image of more icons and I brows from them with choosing position in *.png image.

```
sIcons[c] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            pgePath + 'img/icons.png',
            new google.maps.Size(40, 45),
            new google.maps.Point(c * 40, 90),
            new google.maps.Point(22, 31)
        );
```

40x45 is the size of one icon in the big image (icons.png). But I need display it larger.

I tried to fill 5th argumetn with "new google.maps.Size(80, 90)" but it didn't work.

```
sIcons[c] = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            pgePath + 'img/icons.png',
            new google.maps.Size(40, 45),
            new google.maps.Point(c * 40, 90),
            new google.maps.Point(22, 31),
            new google.maps.Size(80, 90)
        );
```

I don't want upload larger images - i need use this one I already use somewhere else in origin size.

Comment: It looks like you have read [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) 
and it looks like you are doing the right thing.  Perhaps you could provide a link to your map where it doesn't work or a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/councilsites_co_uk_carparks_scale_kml.xml)  that shows scaling working with icons (but not sprites, I don't have an example with sprites)